# How to manually format \ointctrclockwise?

Tags: txfonts

For a wordpress post, I can't use the `txfonts` package for things like:

```
\ointctrclockwise
```

How can I format this manually?

Comment: I have no idea about `WordPress` and its `LaTeX` support, but can you use packages at all? How about `pxfonts`?

Comment: No, the latex support is limited to inline $ latex ... $ markup.

Comment: ...include it as an image...

Comment: How does Wikipedia's markup does this?

Comment: I don't think it does.  Look for example in: 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem

which uses the rather ambiguous \oint in places that an orientation is implied.

Comment: Well, I think, Werner's suggestion is the best way do it for the moment. Blame WordPress ;-) I also fear, that in this sense, your question is somehow off-topic.

Comment: This symbol  is available in stix or asana math or any other Unicode font U+2232 so you should be able to use it directly in a web page as ∲ so long as the fonts are available locally, or you refer to them as web fonts.

Comment: The standard latex plugin makes images which is just evil, https://wordpress.org/plugins/mathjax-latex/ would typeset the mathematics as text and let you use the full symbol range supported by unicode math fonts.

Comment: I haven't forked out the cash required to pay for hosting and control of my own wordpress server and am just using wordpress.com, which doesn't allow changes to the default plugins.

I suppose that if I did that, I'd be able to add extra packages, including my own, and could eliminate this problem directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [WordPress' LaTeX support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/#latex-packages) the following packages are loaded:

- `amsmath`
- `amsfonts`
- `amssymb`

A poor man's solution could be for a `\displaystyle` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathop{\rlap{$\mkern5.5mu\circlearrowright$}\int_0^\infty}
  =
  \mathop{\rlap{$\mkern5.5mu\circlearrowright$}\int\limits_0^\infty}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \displaystyle]

A `\textstyle` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathop{\rlap{$\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\circlearrowright$}}$}{\textstyle\int_{\,0}^\infty}}
  =
  \mathop{\rlap{$\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\circlearrowright$}}$}{\textstyle\int\limits_{0}^{\hbox to 0pt{\hss$\scriptstyle\infty$\hss}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \textstyle]

**Remarks:**

- `\vcenter` is used to center `\circlearrowright` vertically around the math axis.
- `\hbox to 0pt{\hss ... \hss}` is needed for longer sub-/superscripts to ignore their width.
- In the `\nolimits` case, the subscript is moved a little to the right to avoid a collision with the circle.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the embedded $ markers?  Those end the latex context in wordpress.

Comment: @PeeterJoot: `\ensuremath{...}`

Comment: thanks, \mathop{\rlap{\ensuremath{\mkern3.5mu\circlearrowright}}\int} appears to work (although the \int is very short).

Comment: If I understood the question you need the counterclockwise orientation. But \circlearrowleft looks uggly because the integral sign is slanted.

Comment: I wanted both, and they both look ugly ... that's why I always post a pdf version of each blog post.

Comment: This is actually clockwise....

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to compose the character from bold variant of \wedge and normal \oint. The following code was tuned with AMS math fonts and size 10pt. If you are using different size, then you need to edit the dimensions in the code.

```
\font\f=cmbsy7 at2.5pt
\def\ointctrclockwise{\mathop
   {\oint \kern-4.46pt\raise1.8pt\hbox{%
    \rlap{\f\char"5E}\kern.1pt\rlap{\f\char"5E}}}\limits}
```

The result:

[image]